# Error: Value is undefined, expected an Object in React Native Animated Charts Library

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Full error description:-
Error: Value is undefined, expected an Object
This is base example given in [this](https://github.com/rainbow-me/react-native-animated-charts) npm package.Please have a look in this error.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
This error is located at:

in ChartPath (at ChartPath.js:499)
in ChartPathProvider (at Chart.js:69)
in ChartPathProvider (at Chart.js:68)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Chart.js:67)
in Chart (at Home.js:91)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Home.js:83)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at MainLayout.js:37)
in MainLayout (at Home.js:82)
in Home (at SceneView.tsx:122)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:172)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:134)
in Screen (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:30)
in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:166)
in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:172)
in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:146)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
in BottomTabNavigator (at tabs.js:32)
in Tabs (at SceneView.tsx:122)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:573)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:555)
in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:544)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Card.tsx:538)
in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:134)
in Screen (at Screens.tsx:74)
in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:172)
in ScreenContainer (at Screens.tsx:50)
in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:498)
in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
in StackNavigator (at App.js:14)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
in NavigationContainer (at App.js:13)
in Provider (at App.js:12)
in App (at renderApplication.js:47)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)

import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, View} from 'react-native';
import {ChartDot, ChartPath, ChartPathProvider, monotoneCubicInterpolation} from 
'@rainbow-me/animated-charts';

export const {width: SIZE} = Dimensions.get('window');

export const data = [
  {x: 1453075200, y: 1.47}, {x: 1453161600, y: 1.37},
  {x: 1453248000, y: 1.53}, {x: 1453334400, y: 1.54},
  {x: 1453420800, y: 1.52}, {x: 1453507200, y: 2.03},
  {x: 1453593600, y: 2.10}, {x: 1453680000, y: 2.50},
  {x: 1453766400, y: 2.30}, {x: 1453852800, y: 2.42},
  {x: 1453939200, y: 2.55}, {x: 1454025600, y: 2.41},
  {x: 1454112000, y: 2.43}, {x: 1454198400, y: 2.20},
];

const points = monotoneCubicInterpolation({data, range: 40});

const Chart = () => (
  <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
    <ChartPathProvider data={{ points, smoothingStrategy: 'bezier' }}>
      <ChartPath height={SIZE / 2} stroke="yellow" width={SIZE} />
      <ChartDot style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
    </ChartPathProvider>
  </View>
);
export default Chart
```

Comment: please separate the "error log" with code implementation to clarify the question.

Comment: try to remove "stroke" in "ChartPath" and check it again.